# Python for loop counter produces a float instead of a int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is this:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    if test.loc[i, 'Final%'] > 50:
        total += 1
        
print(total)
```

Its a straight forward count, but the output is always a different number and always a float value instead of a integer, and doesn't give any errors. The 'Final%' column is a float64 and contains floats. I have no idea whats going on here. No other code changes happen while I re-run this.

Output that I've gotten:

```
2294.2799999999997,
6218.28,
8180.28,
10142.279999999999,
332.28
```

Suppose to output an integer but outputs random floats.

Comment: Where do you define `total`?

Comment: `total` must be a float before you increment it in the loop.

Comment: You might also consider something like: `test["Final%"].gt(50).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is you are running this in a jupyter notebook. As pointed out by [fsimonjetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15873043/fsimonjetz), you aren't resetting your `total` value to zero before starting the for loop. Adding the line
below before the for loop should fix your problem.

```py
total = 0
```

To convert this into a float you can follow what [Khang Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21153396/khang-nguyen) has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to print 'total' before the loop and in the loop at every iteration to see if the problem is in the loop or before it.

Also you can simplify your loop like this assuming 'test' is iterable:

```
for value in test:
    if value['Final%'] > 50:
        total += 1
```

please post the output of this:

```
print(f'Value before loop = {total}')
for value in test:
    if value['Final%'] > 50:
        total += 1
        print(f'Value inside loop = {total}')
print(f'Value after loop = {total}')
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers.

If I set total = 0 at the start, it gives 1962, which sounds right, but I still dont get why it gave random floats at the start tho.

Comment: Check if you are using the same variable somewhere before this code. You can try also to make this a function and return the 'total' variable

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot, I used total as a counter in another loop further up in the code and after playing around to some more to understand the 'randomness' of the output, I realized that by not setting it to 0 before the loop it keeps adding the wanted total every time I ran the cell. Take away is always make sure you use unique var names and always set to 0. Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
print(int(total))
```

you could try to convert your total into an integer before you print